# How to remove this EXC_BAD Access error?

Tags: swift, uiview, tags

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    myScrollView.delegate = self
    myScrollView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })

    for i in 1...2
    {
        myView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x,22.0,320,83))
        myView.tag = i
        myScrollView.addSubview(myView)
        myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myScrollView.frame.size.width*2,128.0)
    }
}
```

The error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This line is probably not correct:

   ```
    myView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x,22.0,320,83))
   ```

   You are using `myView` in the same line in which you instantiate it. If you examine `myView` before this line is called, it is likely `nil`.
2. Most likely `myScrollView` or `imagePicker` is an implicitly wrapped optional `@IBOutlet` that is `nil`. Examine these values before using them (either by inserting `print` statement, or by adding breakpoint and then examining the values in the debugger). See if either of these are `nil`.

   In terms of why it might be `nil`, the two most common problems are:

   - The outlet can be `nil` if you neglected to hook the `@IBOutlet` in Interface Builder. This can be confirmed by checking the outlets for the scroll view in IB. It can also be quickly confirmed by seeing if the outlet connector in the left margin next to the outlet

     Connected:

     [image]

     Not connected:

     [image]

     or
   - You can also have outlets be `nil` if transitioning to this scene programmatically, but doing so incorrectly (i.e. instantiating this scene from the class rather than from the storyboard).

Comment: I have checked outlet is connected

Comment: No outlet is connected and I am getting error on this line--- myView.tag = i

Comment: OK, so you're saying that the outlet is hooked up in IB, but in `viewDidLoad` the outlet appears to be `nil`? If that's the case, the problem may be how you instantiated the view controller (my second point). How did you instantiate the view controller?

Comment: This is my code----->override func viewDidLoad()
    
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        myScrollView.delegate = self
       //// myScrollView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
//        for i in 1...2
//        {
//            myView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x,22.0,320,83))
//            myView.tag = i
//            myScrollView.addSubview(myView)
//            myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myScrollView.frame.size.width*2,128.0)
//        }
        
    }

Comment: I am getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION while setting the view tag.Please check whether I am setting the tag correctly or not

Comment: I don't think it's the `tag` line. It's either the adding of the view to the scroll view (which is why I'm asking you to verify that that is not `nil`) or it's that very suspicious reference to `myView` in that `CGRect` reference. The `myView` is `nil` at this point .... you cannot use `myView` before it's instantiated.